# docker firebird: error your user name and password are not defined when tries to connect

Tags: docker, firebird, digital-ocean

I use the `jacobalberty/firebird` image to use firebird in docker.

However when I tried to connect using `/usr/local/firebird/bin/isql` inside the container I got error `Your user name and password are not defined.` in the digital ocean environment. Oddly in the local it works fine. here are the command logs for each enviconment

```
# local

root@8978428b8a97:/usr/local/firebird/bin# ./isql
Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database
SQL> CONNECT "/firebird/data/data.GDB"
CON> user 'guest' password 'guest';
Database:  "/firebird/data/data.GDB", User: guest
SQL>
```

local working fine

```
# remote

root@2ef7b23a97a7:/usr/local/firebird/bin# ./isql
Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database
SQL> CONNECT "/firebird/data/data.GDB"
CON> user 'guest' password 'guest';
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 28000
Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login.
```

the remote doesn't

this is the docker compose config

```
  firebirddb:
    image: jacobalberty/firebird:2.5.8-sc 
    networks: 
      - mynetwork
    volumes:
      - ./data:/firebird/data
    environment:
      - ISC_PASSWORD=random12
      - FIREBIRD_USER=guest
      - FIREBIRD_PASSWORD=guest
      - FIREBIRD_DATABASE=data.GDB
```

The file are uploaded to the `.data` where I execute `docker-compose up`. I uploaded the database file using filezilla. What is possibly the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

so apparently the md5 hash doesn't match.
I checked using `md5sum firebird/data/data.GDB`

so I tried to upload the file several times until it matched, then it works. maybe my connection wasn't that good.
but even after it succeeded, there's no table in database, and that's out of the context of this question. Probably I'll post it in another question.

Comment: Instead of uploading a database, consider restoring a backup instead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried using firebird backup (gbak), and the same error message appears. 
I don't know why, but the hash keeps changing and my yesterday upload now returns the same error again.

Comment: That would suggest that, as the error says, your user doesn't exist or you're using the wrong password..